# imagecreatefromgif() returning is not a valid GIF file in

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents

I am trying to pull an image from a .php file on an external site which is a gif (one frame). I want to in the end put these images into a gif but thats not the problem at the moment. Everytime i try to save down the gifs as .pngs it returns the error " is not a valid GIF file in"

```
include('GIFEncoder.class.php');
$user = $_GET['user'];
$url = 'http://link.com/image.php?username=' . $user . '';
$username = explode('=', $url);
$username = $username[1];
$img = 'image_cache/' . $username .'.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
$i = imagecreatefromgif('image_cache/' . $username .  '.gif');
imagepng($i, "image_cache/". $username .".png");
```

the exact error im getting

Warning: imagecreatefromgif() [function.imagecreatefromgif]: 'image_cache/Lexo.gif' is not a valid GIF file in z/projects/gif/index.php on line 9

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you what the problem is?

Comment: What's the url of the external gif?

Comment: Why do you think it's returning a GIF to your script?

Comment: The gif is there as i can see it on the FTP and it works. The external php im grabbing the gif link is http://game.habboon.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage.php?username=Dionysus&direction=4 - The gif is there but it says its not "valid".

Answer (score 2):

The image is actually a png. Run `exif_imagetype` on the file, and you'll see that the type is png. The gif suffix is a mistake. To do what you're trying to do, just name it with a .png suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look more like:

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])){
  header('Content-type:image/png');
  $user = $_GET['user']; $img = imagecreatefrompng("image_cache/$user.png");
  imagepng($img); imagedestroy($img);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP's intention is to save the image, rather than to output it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to fixe the issue somefilename is not a valid GIF file in..imagecreatefromgif()

```
$createFrom = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filepath));
imagecopyresampled();
imagegif();
```